# Appending text to JFrame Component using a method

Tags: java, swing, casting, append, jtextarea

I am creating a program that goes through a text inside a `JTextArea` using a function. Let's call it the `parse()` method. The obligatory needs one parameter that is the text to be parsed and then another parameter that will be a `JFrame` Component.

The `parse()` function goes through each character and determines a course of action using if statements. I also have an array that will store Integers from some other part of the code. On one of the if statements, I need to append the ASCII character from the value of the array.

Here's some of the code I used for the method:

```
//Let's imagine the array has this values 
int arr[] = {0,72,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100,0}; 

//This variable is the index of the array.
int index = 5;

public void parse(String str, Component comp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == 'j') {
            index++;
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == 'l') {
            index--;
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == 'z') {
            arr[index]++;
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == 'x') {
            arr[index]--;
        } else if (str.charAt(i) == 'p') {
            //Here I need to append the ASCII char from the value of the array 
            //where the index variable is at. What I did is this:
            comp.[IDK WHAT SHOULD BE HERE OR IF IT USES PARENTHESIS OR !]String.valueOf((char)arr[index]);
        }
   }
}
```

In the previous code, the char that should be appended to the Component would be an 'o'. How do I do it?

The only way I find it posible is to specify the Component like

```
public void parse(String str, JTextArea ta) {}
```

Yet I wan't to do that for all components of the frame.

Comment: Ask yourself this question, what does it mean to a `Component` to append a character? Since many components don’t actually display text at all, it doesn’t make much sense. Personally, I’d define a `interface` with a `append` method and pass that instead, then it’s up to the caller to define the context of what should be done - to answer your general question - No, it can’t be done using a `Component`

Comment: Where in any component on a JFrame do you hope to **"append"** this character?